# .NET Portability Analysis - .NET Core Compatible, ASP.NET Core Incompatible?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I ran the portability analysis (see below) and I ended up with a confusing (to me) result. If something is compatible with `.NET Core` but not `ASP.NET Core`, is there a way to compile the data code into a `.NET Core App .dll` which can then be consumed by `ASP.NET Core`? Will compiling into a `.NET Core .dll` affect portability of the `ASP.NET Core` app? Could I still run that, say, in a Docker image on Linux?

[image: Portability Analysis Result]

Conversely, this is pretty old code, is there a practice/paradigm that replaces using `DataRowCollection/DataTable` in `ASP.NET Core` I have yet to stumble upon?

Comment: Pay attention to the version number. ASP.NET Core 1.0 is too old (2016 June), so it's API surface is the smallest.

Comment: You can pack your old project as a Nuget package. In a asp.net core app you can make references to Nuget packages, Framework dlls and other visual studio projects.